# What is causing this recursion with my jQuery calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, recursion

I currently have some code written that will call a function after a custom `.trigger()` call. This is what is called:

```
function _visitAddTag(state, listener) {
        if (state.properties.action = "RedoAddTag") contextMenu.unhide();
        var $target = contextMenu.getContextMenuUI().tags; // Grab tag elements
        var callback = function () {
            if (listener) {
                google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
            }
            $target.off("tagIds-updated", callback);
            contextMenu.hide();
            next.call(contextMenu.getTargetLabel(), state.transition);
        };
        $target.on("tagIds-updated", callback());
    }
```

The `next.call()` line causes this method to be triggered:

```
function () { // 'this' is contextMenu.getTargetLabel(), as called in Onboarding.js/_visitAddTag()
                tracker.push('Onboarding_Transition', {onboardingTransition: "tag-attribute-1"});
                var tags = this.getProperty('tagIds');
                return tags == [2] ? "adjust-heading-angle-1" : "redo-tag-attribute-1" // Where 2 is the tag_id of the "points into traffic" tag
            }
```

Where a return value of `"redo-tag-attribute-1"` will cause the whole thing to loop again.

I see the potential for recursion here, especially if the `"tagIds-updated"` event is somehow triggered inside of the second function call. However, when I debug the code, that event is only triggered once. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is happening here? I'm a javascript newb so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: `.on("tagIds-updated", callback())` you should remove the `()` beside `callback`. It will run the callback immediately instead of waiting for the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't wrap my head around the code completely. I see 2 problems in your code at the moment:

1. `$target.on("tagIds-updated", callback());` doesn't really attach an event handler. It's just calling `callback` immediately. You need `$target.on("tagIds-updated", callback);`. Notice the missing `()`.
2. `tags == [2]` will always be `false`. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript). You can probably use `tags.includes(2)` instead. As it stands, that function will always return `"redo-tag-attribute-1"`. Which maybe the root cause of this recursion that you're facing.

Comment: Oh my goodness, it really was just the extra () after the `callback` call. I didn't realize that that would just call it right away. Thank you so much